# rails and ajax SyntaxError {stack: (...), message: "Unexpected token <"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to execute a ajax every 5 seconds an get the json result. But the ajax it's not working I always get:

> SyntaxError {stack: (...), message: "Unexpected token <"}

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function(){ 
  var url = "/hangout_second_user";

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    data: {"username" : "someusername"},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(){
      alert(result);
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
      console.log("Impossible to connect");
      console.log(xhr.statusText);
      console.log(textStatus);
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
  }, 5000);
});
```

Here is the action of my controller:

```
def hangout_second_user
    @incoming_kid = Kid.where(username: params[:username]).first
    prueba = REDIS.smembers "hangout:#{current_kid.id.to_s}"
        if !prueba.empty?
            current_kid.set_busy_status!
            respond_to do |format|
            format.json { render json: "{url:#{prueba[0].to_s}}", success: :ok, error: false }
          end
        end

  end
```

UPDATE

---

I changed the render format like this:

```
format.json { render json: prueba[0].to_json, success: :ok, error: false }
```

but I still getting and html file and that's why I'm getting an error. Any help please

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"? Do you get the "impossible to connect" console log? Wrong content? Not happening every 5 seconds? Errors in the console?

Answer (score 1):

You should use either the $.ajax() function or the $.getJSON() function, as $.getJSON() will also perform an AJAX call.

So a possible solution would be:

```
setInterval(function(){ 

  var url = "/hangout_second_user";

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: {"user_id" : "537c63ea20db9040d2000332"},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result){
      $.each(result, function(i, field){
          alert(result);
      });
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
      console.log("Impossible to connect");
      console.log(xhr.statusText);
      console.log(textStatus);
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
  }, 5000);
```

Or alternatively:

```
setInterval(function(){ 

  var url = "/hangout_second_user";

  $.getJSON(url, {"user_id" : "537c63ea20db9040d2000332"}; function(result) {
      $.each(result, function(i, field){
          alert(result);
      });
    });
  }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant use "#{current_kid.id.to_s}" in javascript. Try storing its value somewhere in hidden _field and access it in javascript

Comment: Yes I can, I'm using HAML and when it render the html I didn't see any rails code, just the user id, But I'll fix the code for you